# How to cancel pending publication in Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I don't know why by small mistake I pressed published app in google play store, and now the state is released app is `'pending publication'`
[image]

My question is how to cancel pending publication?

Answer (score 5):

Wait it to publish,It will take no more than 30 minutes.
Then unpublish it
[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to cancel it before Publishing finished, at the some location there.

Comment: but after 1 hour. it is on pending publication state

Comment: it can not be cancelled from that location